# Completion of Mordell-Weil group $E(K)$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, formal-completions

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension of  a number field and  $E/K$ be an elliptic curve. let $E(K)$ be an Mordel-Weil group of $E/K$.

I encountered a notation $\hat{E(K)}$, which is the completion with respect to the topology defined by the subgroups of finite index. (related:
https://math.stackexchange.com/users/985494/brauermaninobstruction)

The paper I am reading([link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02772219), the bottom of p214)
claims there is a **natural surjection homomorphism** from$\hat{E(K)}$ to $\hat{H^0}(Gal(L/K),E(L))$.
Here, $\hat{H^0}$ denotes Tate-cohomology group (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate_cohomology_group).

I have no idea how to construct surjection from $\hat{E(K)}$ to $\hat{H^0}(Gal(L/K),E(L))$.

To sum up, why(how) can we make surjective homomorphism from from $\hat{E(K)}$ to $\hat{H^0}(Gal(L/K),E(L))$?

P.S. Before I notice a comment from Qiaochu Yuan, I made a mistake. I mistook Tate-cohomology $\hat{H^0}(Gal(L/K),E(L))$ for usual cohomology $H^0(Gal(L/K),E(L))$.

Comment: I don't believe that this is true but the paper is paywalled and I can't access it to check what is being said. Can you quote more of the surrounding text?

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful comment. I mistook Tate-cohomology and usual cohomology. I modified my question.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to see 'the other away around.' Namely, if the Galois extension $L/K$  is finite, then $T$,  the trace/norm of $E(L)$ in $E(K)$, is a subgroup of finite index in $E(K)$ (because it contains $[L:K] E(K)$). Hence the natural map $$\hat H^0(L/K, E(L)) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} E(K)/T \to {E(K)}^\wedge/T^\wedge $$ is an isomorphism.

(The superscript wedges indicate completion. Sorry for the change of notation - it was disturbing me to have hats being used both for Tate cohomology and for completion on the same line.)

*Addendum:*

In answer to the question below - why is $G/H \to G^\wedge/H^\wedge$ an isomorphism.

Suppose that $$\cal C =\{C_i\mid i\in I\},$$ is set of normal, cofinite, cofinal subgroups of $G$. (By 'cofinal', I mean that any normal subgroup of finite index $H$ contains some $C_i$.) The intersection $C_{i_1}\cap \cdots \cap C_{i_n}$ of any finite collection of $C_i$ is also normal and cofinite [as is the product $C_{i_1} \cdots C_{i_n}$]. So if $\cal C$ also contains all such, then one can calculate completion $G^\wedge$ using the $C_i$:
$$ G^\wedge = \varprojlim_{i\in I} G/C_i.$$

In particular (the point), if $H$ is a normal subgroup of finite index in $G$,
then we can in fact calculate $G^\wedge$ with $\cal C$ consisting of subgroups $C_i$ of $H$ ($C_i$ normal and of finite index in $G$).

Now, given $i_1, \cdots, i_n$ a corresponding basis open set $U$ in $G^\wedge$ has component $g_iC_i $ in the $i$th place, where the $g_i $ form a compatible system (for the inverse limit). In fact, if one writes $C = C_{i_1}\cap \cdots C_{i_n}$, then there exists a  $g\in G$ such that

$$g C = g_{i_k} C$$ for $k=1,\cdots,n$.
Thus, pretending that the $i_1,\cdots, i_n$ are the 'first' elements in $I$, $U$ is of the form

$$ U = \{(gC_1,\cdots, gC_n, g_{i}C_i, \cdots)\mid i\not= i_1,\cdots i_n, \text{ and } g C_i \cap C= g_i C\cap C_i\}.$$

In other words, G is dense in $G^\wedge$, so that $G \twoheadrightarrow G^\wedge / W$, for any open normal subgroup $W$ of $G^{\wedge}$.

Now $H^\wedge$ *is* such a subgroup, and the above applies: namely, if $g\in H$, then the equation
$$g_i \equiv g \pmod {C\cap C_i},$$
forces $g_i$ to be an element of $H$, since, by construction/fiat, the $C$ and $C_i$ are all subgroups of $H$.

Therefore
$$ G/H \to G^{\wedge}/H^{\wedge}$$
is an isomorphism.

Comment: Why the isomorphism $E(K)/T\cong \hat{E(K)}/\hat{T}$ holds ? In general, is it true that 'Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be finite index subgroup. Then, $\hat{G}/\hat{H}\cong G/H$ ?

Comment: I was just getting around to 'pre-answer' your question / comment , but you have since accepted the answer, um, are you OK?

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking forward to your answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @BrauerManinobstruction I moved and completed my comments into the 'addendum' above. Hopefully correctly - sorry for the delay.

Comment: @BrauerManinobstruction correction - sigh - for a rather important typo:  $g C = g_{i_k} C$, for $k= 1,\cdots , n$.